# using openni_camera to play a bag problem

Tags: ros, openni, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a .bag file from a kinect which is writing the topics:
camera/depth/image
camera/rgb/camera_info
camera/rgb/image_color/commpresed
/clock
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tf
I am trying to use openni nodelet to play it back ( I need to conect the data to another node)
I am using: roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch device_id:=invalid
and am running setparam sim_time true
and rosbag play fille.bag
My bag file is working but I'm getting this from the openni

Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

**unused args [depth_registered_filtered] for include of [/opt/ros/indigo/share/rgbd_launch/launch/includes/processing.launch.xml]
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file**

any clue how to solve it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236103/using-openni_camera-to-play-a-bag-problem/) by [GGM](https://answers.ros.org/users/26774/ggm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-06-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am pretty new to ros and even to linux. I faced the same error. What I did is the following:

1. go to the location provided in the error '/opt/ros/indigo/share/rgbd_launch/launch/includes/' and using nano or any other editor open the file 'processing.launch.xml'.
2. There will be several sections in there. Under the section 'Remapping Arguments', add this line

(just like the several others already there.)

3. Then try to run 'roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch' again and see if this works.

It solved the error for me, but I do not know why this works.

---

Originally posted by [abhanjac](https://answers.ros.org/users/27211/abhanjac/) with karma: 26 on 2016-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1